# Read data from database to TextFormField

Tags: flutter

I'm able to load data from the database and display it on a TextField. Like this:

```
Text('name: ${addCash.name}'),
```

Can I do the same for `TextFormField()`?
The goal is to read the data to edit/update it and save it back into database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with labelText or hintText this is just for read data.

but if you need to handle input then you set a **TextEditingController** and pass in **TextFormField** ***controller***

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a `TextEditingController`, set its `text` property, and pass the controller as the `controller` parameter of your `TextFormField`. This way, you can easily access the `text` property later on to read the `String` that is being displayed in the `TextFormField` and do whatever you want to do with it.